# iOS app not working on 5th generation devices

Tags: ios, xcode, device

I just updated my iOS app to the store and immediately started getting emails about how the app won't download to 5th generation devices. Sure enough, I looked in the app store and 5th generation is no longer compatible. I never changed the deployment target from iOS 8. [5th generation devices meaning they can no longer use iPhone 5 or iPhone 5c]

I in no way intended this to happen nor do I know how this happened. Is there any way I can check and see what devices are accepted through Xcode? Should I be looking in my info.plist? The only thing I found in the info.plist was required device capabilities where it says armv7 and I know I am using armv7 and arm64 for architectures...I don't think that is the issue though.

Anything helps I am very lost as to why it stopped accepting certain devices??

Comment: What devices are you really talking about when you say 5th generation devices?

Comment: @rmaddy for example, they can no longer use iPhone 5 or iPhone 5c, even though they have the latest iOS

Comment: In iTunes Connect, look at the details for the build of your latest app version. What Device Requirements are shown?

Comment: @rmaddy Okay here is what the Device Requirements are: (1) Minimum iOS Version:
8.0  (2)  Supported Architectures: arm64 (3) Device Family: iPhone / iPod touch, iPad (4) Required Capabilities: arm64

Comment: There's your problem. Your app only supports arm64 devices. Check the settings for the Release build in Xcode. Make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to `No` for `Release` builds. And make sure the other architecture settings include arm7 or arm7s.

Comment: @rmaddy YOU ARE A SAINT! Thank you so much.

Comment: UPDATE: I also had to remove required device capabilities in the info.p-list